# Triple covers of $\mathbb{P}^2$ with fixed branch locus

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-surfaces

Let us consider a smooth (complex) cubic surface $X \subset \mathbb{P}^3$ and a general point $p \notin X$. Then it is classically well-known that linear the projection $$\pi_p \colon X \longrightarrow \mathbb{P}^2$$ is a triple cover whose branch locus $B$ is a sextic plane curve with six cusps lying on  a conic. Conversely, given such a sextic $B \subset \mathbb{P}^2$ there exists a triple cover as above.

> **Question.** Let $B \subset \mathbb{P}^2$ be a *fixed* plane sextic with six cusps on a conic. What is the dimension of the space of cubics surfaces $X \subset \mathbb{P}^3$ that admit a projection branched over $B$?

I'm rather sure that this must be written somewhere in Zariski's work, but I was not able to find it. Anyway, any reference is appreciated.

Comment: Are you asking about the dimension in the $\mathbb{P}^{19}$ of all cubic surfaces, or in the $4$-dimensional quotient by the action of $\textbf{PGL}_4$?  I would have guessed that in the $4$-dimensional quotient you get a discrete set of such cubics, since the topological type is determined by the monodromy action, and then the complex structure away from the ramification locus is uniquely determined as well.

Comment: Right, I would like to know the dimension of the "moduli space", namely the dimension of the quotient by the $\mathbf{PGL}_4$-action. So, if I understand correctly,  you say that it should be zero by Riemann Extension Theorem. Is this 0-dimensional space a finite set? A single point?

Comment: There is a naive bound on the size of the set.  The open complement of the sextic plane curve has finitely presented fundamental group.  The set of homomorphisms of that group into $S_3$ (up to conjugation) is an upper bound.  But it is probably an overestimate: most topological coverings of a quasi-projective variedy do not "close up" to a proper analytic space (the one-dimensional case is an exception).  Even if there is a proper covering, why should it be a cubic surface?

Comment: If the cover $X$ is a proper analytic space, then it is algebraic by Riemann and Grauert-Remmert  Extension Theorems  (Serre, Topics in Galois Theory, Thm. 6.1.4), so a projective surface. Then it is no too difficult to show that it is smooth and actually a cubic surface, see http://arxiv.org/abs/1605.02102, Prop. 3.3.

Comment: Furthermore, if I'm not mistaken, it seems to me that, since the branch locus $B \subset \mathbb{P}^2$ is an algebraic curve, then the cover is necessarily projective-algebraic. This should follow again by Grauert-Remmert applied to the unramified cover over the complement $\mathbb{P}^2-B$. See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/40791/finite-covers-of-complex-varieties-all-but-two-questions-answered

Comment: Let $U $ be a quasi-projective scheme over $\mathbb C$, e.g. , $U= \mathbb P^2 - B$. Then the topological fundamental group of $U$ is finitely generated; see SGA7, tome I, Expose II, Theoreme 2.3.1. In particular, for all $d\geq 1$, the set of finite etale covers of $U$ of degree $d$ is finite (up to equivalence). Therefore, $\mathbb P^2 -B$ has only finitely many finite etale covers of degree $3$. Normalization now tells us that the category of finite covers of degree three of $\mathbb P^3$ ramified precisely along $B$ is equivalent to...

Comment: ...the category of finite etale covers of $\mathbb P^2 -B$ of degree $3$. It follows that, as Jason Starr mentioned, the set of cubic surfaces with the desired property is finite.

Comment: Thanks. And from this + Grauert-Remmert extension it follows that every such a cover is algebraic (hence projective), right?

Comment: Yes,  although in your set-up Riemann's existence theorem (Theorem 5.1 in SGA 1, Expose XII)  might already be enough to conclude. (Note that to prove Grauert-Remmert  one uses Riemann's existence theorem; see Theorem 5.4 in loc . cit..)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A sextic with 6 cusps on a conic has a unique (up to obvious equivalence) *torus structure*, i.e., a representation of the equation in the form $f_2^3+f_3^2=0$, where $\deg f_i=i$. (Note $\{f_2=0\}$ is necessarily the conic and, in fact, the six cusps are the intersection of the two curves $\{f_i=0\}$.) Then, it is more or less obvious that this polynomial is the discriminant (with respect to an extra variable) of a unique cubic polynomial. Thus, the cubic is unique.

Of course, over $\mathbb{C}$ the same conclusion follows from the fact that $\pi_1$ of the complement, which is the modular group $\langle u,v\,|\,u^2=v^3=1\rangle$, has a unique epimorphism to $S_3$.

Comment: Thanks. I agree with your second proof (over $\mathbb{C}$). Why do you claim that it is "more or less" obvious that the polynomial is the discriminant of a unique cubic polynomial (up to multiplicative scalars)? I clearly see one of these polynomials, namely $$z^3+bz+c, \quad b=-f_2/\sqrt[3]{4}, \, c=f_3/ \sqrt{-27},$$ but  is it immediate that there are no others?

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi: Yes. Any polynomial $z^3+bz+c$ gives rise to a torus structure, and the latter is unique. (Extra roots of unity are compensated by coordinate changes.) For the uniqueness, the conic $f_2=0$ passes through all cusps, and the cubic $f_3=0$ is tangent to the curve at each cusp, so both are overdetermined (or, one can use Bezout's theorem). BTW, it may happen that one or both split; they should just be transversal at the intersection points.

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi Of course, this polynomial is unique up to coordinate changes: one should first bring it to the reduced form $z^3+bz+c$. In particular, we assume that the characteristic is not $3$ or $2$ (just in case), in case you care about positive characteristic.

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi I guess I should also mention that all this applies to a sextic with exactly 6 cusps. This works for most other sextics of torus type that are not too degenerate. However, a sextic with 8 cusps has 4 torus structure (each selecting 6 out of the 8 cusps). Most interesting are 9-cuspidal sextics: each admits 13 coverings, of which **only 12** are cubics!

Comment: When you write "I guess I should also mention that all this applies to a sextic with exactly 6 cusps" I guess you mean "with exactly six cusps *on a conic*", right?

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi Yes, of course on a conic. I just wanted to warn you that there may be more degenerate singularities "on a conic", either due to a singular cubic or non-generic projection. In **most** cases, a torus structure is unique, but there are a few exceptions (e.g., nine cusps automatically constitute 12 sextuples lying on 12 conics; this is also the only case when there is an extra covering that is **not** a cubic). As above, torus structures $\leftrightarrow$ cubics is a bijection.

Comment: Thank you again. A sextic with 9 cusps is the dual of a smooth cubic, right? If so, you say that there are 13 non-equivalent coverings over such a sextic, but In this paper by Kulikov it is claimed instead that there are four. 
http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9803144v1.pdf
Am I missing something?

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi: He claims there is **one** of degree 3; the others are of degree 4. According to his definition of "generic", he counts just the one that is **not** a cubic; each of the the 12 cubics has three cusps (the three cusps that are not on the chosen conic). The maximal dihedral quotient of $\pi_1$ in this case is $\mathbb{D}[\mathbb{Z}_3^3]$, so there are 13 quotients to $S_3$.

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi: This must all be very classical, but being ignorant, I can only refer to my paper (see S 4): Alex Degtyarev. Oka's conjecture on irreducible plane sextics. J. London Math. Soc., 78:2 (2008), 329--351 doi:10.1112/jlms/jdn029. Lots of other stuff on sextics in general and torus type in particular is found on [my web page](http://www.fen.bilkent.edu.tr/~degt/papers/papers.htm) :)